# Positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, determinants

We have $a_1,a_2,...,a_n\in (0,1)$ and matrix 
M=
\begin{bmatrix}2a_1&a_2&a_3&.&.\\a_2&2a_2&a_3&.&.\\a_3&a_3&2a_3&.&.\\.&.&.&.&.\end{bmatrix}

We need to check if M is positive definite.

I am trying to evaluate it's determinant as a polynomial in $a_i$ as principal minor are of the same type. And using that frame a condition for positive definiteness of M.

Comment: What is the question? "Is there a better way to do that?"

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no, I am unable to find the determinant

Comment: Try the case $n = 2$ and you'll find that the answer depends on whether $a_2$ is smaller than $4a_1$ or not. I haven't tried $n = 3$ but please try it first and see if you can observe a pattern. If yes, then try to prove it; otherwise I don't know what kind of answer you should expect for this question - in other words, what does "we need to check" mean in your post.

Comment: A right forum for such type questions is math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user64494 Could you expand on your reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D_n$ is the leading principal minor of order $n$, then it seems to me
you should have
$$D_n = 2 a_n D_{n-1} - a_n^2 D_{n-2}$$

Comment: Can you give some hint how you get D_{n-2} term

Comment: Actually I found it empirically.  But it should be provable...

Comment: Yeah it seems correct, but wasn't visible to me initially. Thanks a lot.